# Return zero count where data does not exist

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Documents in my mongodb data collection follows this format,

```
[ 
  {
    "_id": xxxxxxxxx,
    "crime_type": "illegal_trade",
    "crime_year": "2013",
    "location": "Kurunegala"
  },
  {
    "_id": xxxxxxxxx,
    "crime_type": "illegal_trade",
    "crime_year": "2013",
    "location": "Colombo"
  },
  {
    "_id": xxxxxxxxx,
    "crime_type": "illegal_trade",
    "crime_year": "2014",
    "location": "Kandy"
  },
  {
    "_id": xxxxxxxxx,
    "crime_type": "murder",
    "crime_year": "2013",
    "location": "Kadawatha"
  }
]
```

When I run this aggregate operation,

```
db.collection.aggregate(
   [
     { $group : { _id : {type: "$crime_type", year: "$crime_year"}, count: { $sum: 1 } } }
   ]
)
```

The result contains only the items that have `count > 0`

for an example the results for `_id : {type: "murder", year: "2014"}` in which `count = 0` won't include in the results.

My question is,
**How should I alter my query so that those `count = 0` items are also in the results?**

In other words how to do something like [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/46fe0e/1) with mongodb...?

Comment: your document begin with **{{** !. It is one document or multiple docs?

Comment: @Disposer multiple docs..

Comment: I tried your query and got this result: **{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "type" : "murder",
                "year" : "2013"
            },
            "count" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "type" : "illegal_trade",
                "year" : "2014"
            },
            "count" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "type" : "illegal_trade",
                "year" : "2013"
            },
            "count" : 2
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}**

Comment: Yep it works. But I want the results to include `"count": 0` items too. for an example the result should also contain `{ "_id" : { "type" : "murder", "year" : "2014" }, "count" : 0 }`... I want to know if there is a way to do that?  @Disposer

Comment: how could it contain combination that doesnt exist in database? YOu want mongodb to guess all possible combinations?

Comment: Yes. Is it not possible? I'm new to mongodb.. :) @Jarema

Comment: It is not. Response would be infinite. Every possible year for every possible word ;).

You have to deal with it on application side with simple if for every year You want to be included.

Comment: Actually not every possible year and word pair. Only the years and words that are currently in the database. So it won't be infinite... I'm currently handling in the application side. But just wanted to know if it's possible.. `mysql` joins can be used to create such pairs I think. But may be impossible with mongodb... @Jarema

Comment: please show us how it may be done with joins ( i dont even know what joins have to do with aggregation in sql or nosql. its not their purpose, afaik), and maybe we will be able to do it in mongo. anyways - its easy on application side with few queries, and not so easy with one.

Comment: btw - i never saw a query result, that represents data NOT stored in db. maybe I'm blind.

Comment: @Jarema, This is how it's done with `mysql joins` : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/46fe0e/1 . I'm doing this to the 2 columns `district` and `crime_type` of the table `crime_entity_group` here..

**select distinct 
  c.crime_type, 
  c.district, 
  (select count(*) from crime_entity_group where crime_entity_group.crime_type = c.crime_type and crime_entity_group.district = c.district) count
from
  (select crime_type, district from 
  (select crime_type from crime_entity_group ) a, 
  (select district from crime_entity_group) b) c**

Comment: @Jarema I don't understand what you mean by your last comment. (the one you said you might be blind)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically what you are asking for is results that are not present in the data, so where that key combination does not exist then you return a count of 0. In truth, no database system "truly" does this, but there are ways to make it look like that is happening. But it also means understanding what is really happening to make that so.

It is true that the SQL approach to this would be to make a sub-query of the expected keys from distinct values and then "join" that to the existing dataset in order to create "false positives" for grouping accumulation. That is the general method there, but of course there is the basic "joining" concept which is not supported by MongoDB for reasons of scalability. Whole different argument there, just accept that MongoDB does not do joins on it's own server architecture, and likely never will.

As such, the task of creating that "false set" when working with MongoDB is relegated to a client side ( and consider this only in terms of "client" is a separate process to the database server ) operation. So you essentially get both the "result set" and the "blank set" and "merge" the results.

Different language approaches vary, but here is an efficient listing for node.js:

```
var async = require('async'),
    mongo = require('mongodb'),
    MongoClient = mongo.MongoClient,
    DataStore = require('nedb'),
    combined = new DataStore();

var data = [
  {
    "crime_type": "illegal_trade",
    "crime_year": "2013",
    "location": "Kurunegala"
  },
  {
    "crime_type": "illegal_trade",
    "crime_year": "2013",
    "location": "Colombo"
  },
  {
    "crime_type": "illegal_trade",
    "crime_year": "2014",
    "location": "Kandy"
  },
  {
    "crime_type": "murder",
    "crime_year": "2013",
    "location": "Kadawatha"
  }
];


MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/test',function(err,db) {

  if (err) throw err;

  db.collection('mytest',function(err,collection) {
    if (err) throw err;

    async.series(
      [
        // Clear collection
        function(callback) {
          console.log("Dropping..\n");
          collection.remove({},callback);
        },

        // Insert data
        function(callback) {
          console.log("Inserting..\n");
          collection.insert(data,callback);
        },

        // Run parallel merge
        function(callback) {
          console.log("Merging..\n");
          async.parallel(
            [
              // Blank Distincts
              function(callback) {
                collection.distinct("crime_year",function(err,years) {
                  if (err) callback(err);
                  async.each( years, function(year,callback) {
                    collection.distinct("crime_type",function(err,types) {
                      if (err) callback(err);
                      async.each( types, function(type,callback) {
                        combined.update(
                          { "type": type, "year": year },
                          { "$inc": { "count": 0 } },
                          { "upsert": true },
                          callback
                        );
                      },callback);
                    });
                  },callback);
                });
              },

              // Result distincts
              function(callback) {
                collection.aggregate(
                  [
                    { "$group": {
                      "_id": {
                        "type": "$crime_type",
                        "year": "$crime_year"
                      },
                      "count": { "$sum": 1 }
                    }}
                  ],
                  function(err,results) {
                    async.each( results, function(result, callback) {
                      combined.update(
                        { "type": result._id.type, "year": result._id.year },
                        { "$inc": { "count": result.count } },
                        { "upsert": true },
                        callback
                      );
                    },callback);

                  }
                );
              }
            ],
            function(err) {
              callback(err);
            }
          )

        },

        // Retrieve result
        function(callback) {
          console.log("Fetching:\n");
          combined.find({},{ "_id": 0 }).sort(
            { "year": 1, "type": 1 }).exec(function(err,results) {
            if (err) callback(err);
            console.log( JSON.stringify( results, undefined, 4 ) );
            callback();
          });
        }
      ],
      function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        db.close();
      }
    )

  });

});
```

And this will return a result that not only "combines" results for grouped keys, but also contains a `0` entry for "murder" in year "2014":

```
[
    {
        "type": "illegal_trade",
        "year": "2013",
        "count": 2
    },
    {
        "type": "murder",
        "year": "2013",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "type": "illegal_trade",
        "year": "2014",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "type": "murder",
        "year": "2014",
        "count": 0
    }
]
```

So consider what the meat of the operations is here, mostly within the "parallel" section of the code under "Merging", as this is an efficient way for node to issue all of the queries (and potentially quite a few) all at the same time.

The first part in order to get the "blank" results with no count is essentially a double loop operation, where the point is to get the distinct values for each of "year" and "type". Whether you use the [`.distinct()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) method as shown here or the or using the [`.aggregate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) method with a "cursor" for output and iteration is a matter of how much data you have or what you personally like. For a small set an generation then `.distinct()` is fine with the results in memory. But we want to create "blank" or `0` count entries for each possible pairing, or more importantly including those that are "non existent" as a pairing in the dataset.

Secondly, and in parallel where possible, the aggregation result is run with the standard results. Of course these results will not return a count for "murder" in "2014" because there is none. But this is what basically comes down to merging the results.

The "merge" is basically working with a "hash/map/dict" ( whatever your term is ), of the combined keys for "year" and "type". So you just use that structure, adding the key where it does not exist or incrementing the "count" value on that key where it does. That's an age old operation, and essentially the basis of all aggregation techniques.

The neat little thing being done here ( not that you need to use it ), is the use of [**nedb**](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb), which is a nice little module that allows the use of MongoDB "like" operations on in-memory or other self contained data files. Think of it like SQLite to SQL RDBMS operations. Only a little lighter on the complete functionality.

Part of the point here is that the "hash merge" functions now look like regular MongoDB ["upsert"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-option) operations to the code. In fact, the same code essentially applies if you have a large result that needs to end up in a "result collection" on the server instead.

The overall point is that this is effectively a "join" operation or otherwise a "fill in the blanks" operation depending on the overall size and expectancy of "keys" in your operation. The MongoDB server is not going to do this, but there is nothing stopping you from writing what is effectively your own "data layer" as a middle tier between your end application and the database. Such a distributed server model can be scaled out so that this service level performs these sorts of "joining" operations.

All of the queries used to get the data to merge can effectively be run in parallel under the right coding environment, so while this may not seem as straightforward as the SQL approach to doing this, it can however still be very effective and efficient at actually processing the results.

The approach is different, but then again that is part of the philosophy here. MongoDB relagates "joining" activities to different parts of your application architecture in order to keep it's own server specific operations more efficient, and mostly with regards to sharded clusters. "Joining" or this "Hash Merge" is a "code" function that can be handled by other infrastructure than the database server.